# Blender .DXF export object color information

Tags: export

I have the same models in blender and 3d max that I export to .dxf files.

MAX scene (3d max 2012 design)
[image]

Blender scene (Blender 3.6)
[image]

If I open both files in either **Autodesk Viewer Online** or **DWG Trueview** software, the .dxf files from MAX shows colors while the Blender files do not.

Autodesk Viewer Online (dxf from max)
[image]

Autodesk Viewer Online (dxf from blender)
[image]

DWG Trueview (dxf from max)
[image]

DWG Trueview (dxf from blender)
[image]

I realize that export settings in both softwares are different but with blender I have tried ALL export settings and I have even tried dxf exporter plugins but to no avail.

Is there any way to make blender push out color information for objects in dxf format at all?

Please also kindly let me know if there is perhaps another stack community or website where I could also ask for more information regarding this issue?

Thank you.

**Edit**: Adding additional information to make my question more understandable.

In 3d max, you can set an objects "wireframe" color, this is not the diffuse color but a separate setting. I want to be able to export the wireframe/object color from blender IF its possible. Currently that is probably the Object Properties >> View layer >> Object Color information what im talking about.

[image]

However I would also be satisfied if it was base color
[image]
of a (principled BDSF) material. In fact I think that information would be more likely to be exported within a DXF file.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures)

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie & John Eason, unfortunately this does not answer my question. I have no problems with the textures. I want to be able to export the wireframe (3d max specific)/object color from blender IF its possible to assign and export that information from blender. Ill edit my initial question.

Comment: Looking at [Export - AutoCAD DXF — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_dxf.html#export), it does not seem to be documented. So unless the developer who made that exporter intentionally programmed a way to export a data (that Blender doesn't have to begin with) by using another data, I guess this isn't supported.

Comment: @L0Lock ah thanks, I should've checked there. Okay I guess this is not supported yet then. Thank you.